# DFS Recursion, Revisiting nodes, even after being marked as visited

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

So, I've been trying to run this simple DFS code using recursion and I have marked the already nodes as visited, but it kept looping around the visited nodes again, so I noticed that the boolean array `isVisited` gets created again at every recursion step, and I'm not able to place the array outside this method, in the class, and use it inside the method. Any help would be appreciated! :)

```
private boolean hasRoutesDFS(int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0 || start > graph.size() || end < 0 || end > graph.size())
        return false;
    boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[graph.size() + 1];

    if (start == end)
        return true;
    else{
         isVisited[start]=true;
        System.out.print(start + "->");
        for (int v : graph.getEdge(start)) {
            if (!isVisited[v] ) {
                isVisited[v] = true;
                hasRoutesDFS(v, end);
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

EDIT :
Alright, so thanks to the trick provided in the answer, I was able to fix the code, and now it seems to be working on newer test cases as well, but it still seems wrong at some level, suppose I give the code a graph the following edges:
(endpoint 1) (endpoint 2)
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 4
3 5
4 5
4 6
5 6

And if I search DFS from node 1 to 5, the answer I get is 1->2->3->5, which is a valid path, but there could've been a deeper 1->2->4->6->5 path as well, isn't that what DFS supposed to do? Travel the complete depth?

New Code:

```
private boolean hasRoutesDFS(int start, int end) {
    return hasRoutesDFS(start, end, new boolean[graph.size() + 1]);
}

private boolean hasRoutesDFS(int start, int end, boolean[] isVisited) {
    if (start < 0 || start > graph.size() || end < 0 || end > graph.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (start == end) {
        System.out.print(start);
        return true;
    } else {
        isVisited[start] = true;
        System.out.print(start + "->");
        for (int v : graph.getEdge(start)) {
            if (!isVisited[v]) {
                if(hasRoutesDFS(v,end,isVisited))
                    return true;
                hasRoutesDFS(v, end, isVisited);
            }
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard *trick* to make a recursive function use static data is to pass the static data as a parameter and create it from the base signature.

```
private boolean hasRoutesDFS(int start, int end) {
    return hasRoutesDFS(start, end, new boolean[graph.size() + 1]);
}

private boolean hasRoutesDFS(int start, int end, boolean[] isVisited) {
    if (start < 0 || start > graph.size() || end < 0 || end > graph.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (start == end) {
        return true;
    } else {
        isVisited[start] = true;
        System.out.print(start + "->");
        for (int v : graph.getEdge(start)) {
            if (!isVisited[v]) {
                isVisited[v] = true;
                hasRoutesDFS(v, end, isVisited);
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Not suggesting in any way that the rest of your code is correct (it actually looks wrong to me). Just showing you how to avoid the problem you are seeing wit a new array being created at each call.

Comment: It's only a trick if there is a more legitimate way to do it.

Comment: Don't forget the `isVisited` variable in the actual recursive call ;-) (last line on the deepest nesting level)

Comment: @ScottHunter - I'd say a more legitimate way would be to encapsulate the array as an instance of an object but OP may not have covered OOP yet.

Comment: @jornane - Thanks! Missed that. :)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - I made the BFS code on similar lines and it works perfectly, and the logic here seems fine to me, can you please tell me why it looks wrong to you?

Comment: @codeninja - I'd expect to see a matching `isVisited[x] = false` for every set to `true` on the way out of recursion.

Comment: @codeninja - I'd also expect something like `if (hasRoutesDFS(v, end, isVisited)) return true`. You are completely ignoring the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon
    `if (hasRoutesDFS(v, end, isVisited)) return true;` 

This is basically ignoring the already visited nodes, right?
I think when I put  `if(!isVisited[v])`, that itself checked the condition and used the result of the recursive call?

P.S. Although, my code seems to be working now! Thanks so much for that trick! :)

Comment: @codeninja - I suspect you have not tested your code enough. I would suggest you build a graph with a known route and check this method finds it.